# DOM Element.Closest Child

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When querying the DOM, is there any reason why labels aren't available as children?

```js
var el = document.getElementById("myEl");
var group = el.closest(".form-group");
var ipt =  el.closest(".form-group > input");
var lbl =  el.closest(".form-group > label");
console.log(ipt);
console.log(lbl);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label>Name
      <i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myEl" value.bind="location.name & validate">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because it does not look up the tree than down

Comment: Because `label` is a sibling of the input, not a parent/ancestor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: Also, why does it work for the `<input>`? Note that "The Element.closest() method returns the closest ancestor of the current element (*or the current element itself*) which matches the selectors given in parameter." The `<input>` itself is returned because it matches the `> input` selector, but it doesn't match the `> label` selector.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to select the parent and than look for the child, there is no way to combine it. With your code, it is looking for a parent that is an input or a label.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("myEl");
var group = el.closest(".form-group");
var ipt =  group.querySelector("input");
var lbl =  group.querySelector("label");
console.log(ipt);
console.log(lbl);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label>Name
      <i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myEl" value.bind="location.name & validate">
  </div>
</div>
```